# Prompt user for N (integer) and print a row of asterisks

Tags: asterisk

I am having trouble with this code , I am suppose to prompt the user for an integer N and then print the 'lower left' triangle of asterisks, with N lines so lets say `N=5` then print :

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Here's what I have so far.

```
def tri(x):
   N = 0
   while N == x:
   print '*' * 1 
   print '*' * 2
   print '*' * 3
   etc...
   N = N + 1

print tri(x)
```

I don't think I am doing it properly...anyhow

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PHP script that works

```
function Tri($x){
   $N = 0; //this flag makes sure you add one (*) each line
   for($i = 0; $i <= $x; $i++) //this loop is for each row of asterisk
   {
       for($j = 0; $j < $N; $j++) //this nested loop adds one more asterisk each line
       {
           echo "*"; 
       }
       echo "<br>";
       $N++;
   }
}
```